# Infer header names pandas dataframe for numeric type

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID         91  57 60  79  888 111
06/03/2015  1   2   2   4   1   1
03/03/2015  1   2   2   2   2   3
06/04/2015  1   2   2   2   1   1
17/04/2015  1   3   2   2   1   3
21/04/2015  3   2   1   1   2   1
12/05/2015  1   3   2   2   2   3
```

I have a csv file with columns of ID's (numeric value) and a value (1-4) assigned to each ID for certain dates. Ultimately I would like to have the data in the following format:

```
    Date       Score ID
    06/03/2015  1   91
    03/03/2015  1   91
    06/04/2015  1   91
    17/04/2015  1   91
    21/04/2015  3   91
    12/05/2015  1   91     
    06/03/2015  2   57
    03/03/2015  2   57
    06/04/2015  2   57  
    17/04/2015  3   57  
    21/04/2015  2   57  
    12/05/2015  3   57
```

etc...

**Attempt:**

My thinking is to start by creating a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=', ', delimiter=None, header='infer')
```

The problem I am having is that `infer` does not seem to be able to detect the header names as the values are numeric?

From here, I am hoping to perform dataframe operations to get the data into the desired format

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? `ID` is column name?

Comment: @jezrael. Thank you for your suggestions. I am trying to get your solution working now. print(df.columns) gives Index(['ID', '91', '57', '60', '79', '888','111'],  dtype='object', length=7)

Comment: OK, then is possible use my first solution with melt. If first column is `ID`, then use second solution with unstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with rename columns if necessary:

```
#s\+ is space separator, if necessary change it
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\s+')

d = {'ID':'Date'}
cols = ['Date','Score','ID']
df = df.rename(columns=d).melt('Date', var_name='ID', value_name='Score')[cols]

#convert ID column to int
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)
print (df)
         Date  Score   ID
0  2015-06-03      1   91
1  2015-03-03      1   91
2  2015-06-04      1   91
3  2015-04-17      1   91
4  2015-04-21      3   91
5  2015-12-05      1   91
6  2015-06-03      2   57
7  2015-03-03      2   57
8  2015-06-04      2   57
...
```

But if first column is index is possible use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\s+', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
```

Then is possible convert all columns to int:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)

cols = ['Date','Score','ID']
df = df.unstack().rename_axis(('ID','Date')).reset_index(name='Score')[cols]
print (df)

         Date  Score   ID
0  2015-06-03      1   91
1  2015-03-03      1   91
2  2015-06-04      1   91
3  2015-04-17      1   91
4  2015-04-21      3   91
5  2015-12-05      1   91
6  2015-06-03      2   57
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

for example:

```
import pandas as pd

#Read the data from a txt
path = ' '
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = '\s+' ,header  = 0)

#Use melt to flatten the dataframe and set ID column as index
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID']).set_index('ID')
```

Output:

> ID      variable  value
>
> 06/03/2015   91      1
>
> 03/03/2015   91      1
>
> 06/04/2015   91      1
>
> 06/03/2015   57      2

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This also worked well for me!